# Grunt task for the tailwind in magento 2 frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, development, custom-theme, grunt

We are working on the custom theme with the tailwindCSS.
Normal Magento flow is taking a long time to reflect the changes on the browser.
My question is there any configuration or way to use Grunt to replace or update my compiled CSS from  *app/design/frontend/Vendor/vendor_child/web/css/styles.css* to */pub*? with the single command
and I don't know how to achieve this kindly help me or share your suggestion with this.